# SqlDataReader is not returning all rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, c#-4.0, ado.net

My SQL command returns 3 rows which is verified in a SQL Server GUI. I run the exact same code and the SqlDataReader only returns 2 of them. The same sql command returns 3 rows with `SqlDataAdapter`.

Here is my code - `ds` has 3 rows. Just to show the difference, I have added `SqlDataAdapter`.

Thanks in advance.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VPO"].ConnectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A.account_id, A.fname, A.lname, 
                  FROM T_Test1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
                  JOIN T_Test2 AF WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Account_id=AF.Account_id
                  WHERE account_status = 'A' AND A.card IS NOT NULL
                    AND A.dateFrom >= '09-02-2013 00:00:00' 
                    AND A.dateFrom <= '09-30-2013 00:00:00' 
                    AND AF.code = 'INE'";

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection);
    command.CommandTimeout = 3600;

    connection.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    { 
        while (reader.Read())
        {}
    }

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command.CommandText, connection);
    da.Fill(ds);
}
```

I found the solution:
One of the line in using section is reading the first record. In while loop, it is reading from second record. I removed the below if condition and it worked fine. Thank you all for your replies. Sorry for not posting that line, as I thought that line is handling only exception.

```
if (!reader.Read()) 
    throw new ApplicationException("MISSING Transaction Returned By Financial Institution. Transaction was not found in the database."); 
while (reader.Read()) {}
```

Comment: your code look fine, can you post what you have written in your while loop ?

Comment: I always populated my listviews using the same code. it's perfect! you might be missing something in your while loop.

Comment: @RajVish Post the code inside `while (reader.Read())` .

Comment: The reader is returning all rows, you are using it correctly. Your query does not produce the correct rows.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a class..

```
public class AccountDetails
{
    public int AccountId {get; set;}  
    public string FName {get; set;}     
    public string LName {get; set;} 
}
```

And then return a List of AccontDetails like this...

```
public List<AccountDetails> GetAccountDetails()
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VPO"].ConnectionString))
    {
        string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A.account_id, A.fname, A.lname, 
                      FROM T_Test1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
                      JOIN T_Test2 AF WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Account_id=AF.Account_id
                      WHERE account_status = 'A' AND A.card IS NOT NULL
                        AND A.dateFrom >= '09-02-2013 00:00:00' 
                        AND A.dateFrom <= '09-30-2013 00:00:00' 
                        AND AF.code = 'INE'";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql.ToString(), connection);
        command.CommandTimeout = 3600;

        connection.Open();
        var accDetails = new List<AccountDetails>();

        using (var rdr = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        var accountDetails = new AccountDetails{
                            AccountId = rdr.GetInt32(0),
                            FName = rdr.GetString(1),
                            LName = rdr.GetString(2)
                        };
                        accDetails.Add(accountDetails);
                    }                   
            }
    }

    return accDetails;
}
```

syntax might be out as I did some of this freehand.

This is lighter than using a `DataSet`, unless you specifically need to use a DataSet.  If so, let me know and I will update the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use the `command` when it is out of scope (after the using block), but maybe it was just an example for the `SqlDataAdapter`.

Anyway, there are some guidelines when using the `SqlDatareader`,

try to use this code:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VPO"].ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT DISTINCT A.account_id, A.fname, A.lname, 
                  FROM T_Test1 A WITH (NOLOCK) 
                  JOIN T_Test2 AF WITH (NOLOCK) ON A.Account_id=AF.Account_id
                  WHERE account_status = 'A' AND A.card IS NOT NULL
                    AND A.dateFrom >= '09-02-2013 00:00:00' 
                    AND A.dateFrom <= '09-30-2013 00:00:00' 
                    AND AF.code = 'INE'";

    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    { 
        command.CommandTimeout = 3600;             
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        { 
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                 // Read the data here and do your thing...
            }
            reader.Close(); // We should close this reader - This line is for readability
        }
    }  
}
```

Works for me every time.

Answer (score 0):

Using **SqlDataAdapter** is wrong. You have to use like belov: This solution can solve your problem.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: I guess he has done the same thing... by passing the CommandText

Answer (score 0):

```
 con.Open();    
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();    
         while (reader.Read())    
      {

         // Do stuff here     
      }
    con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the line in using section is reading the first record. In while loop, it is reading from second record. I removed the below if condition and it worked fine. Thank you all for your replies. Sorry for not posting that line, as I thought that line is handling only exception.

if (!reader.Read())
 throw new ApplicationException("MISSING Transaction Returned By Financial Institution. Transaction was not found in the database.");
while (reader.Read())
{}

Comment: you should *update* your question with the answer. That will help users get the correct answer or mark the post as the accepted answer.